# Need to have Do/While loop to work with NOT operator for Characters with a Switch Statement cases

Tags: c, switch-statement

How do I make this so if the char '3' is picked the loop ends or if I type any characters other than 1 or 2 it goes to the default?

I'm used them as characters to fix a bug where if I type anything other than numbers entry it causes a weird crazy loop.

```
void menu(double data[], double output[], int *count){

    int count1 = *count;
    char com;

    do{
        com = displaymenu(&count1);
        switch(com){
            case '1':
                 enterdata(data, &count1);
                 break;
            case '2':
                 processdata(data, output, &count1);
                 displaydata(data, output, &count1);
                 break;
            case '3':
                 printf("Have a nice day!!!\n\n\n\n\n");
                 break;
            default: 
                 printf("Not a Valid Option \n\n\n");
                 break; 
        }
    }while(com != '3');

}

int displaymenu(int *count1){

    int count2 = *count1; 
    char choice;

    printf("*------------------------------------------------------------*\n");
    printf("|    Mini Stats Package                Data Entries = %3d    |\n",count2);
    printf("*------------------------------------------------------------*\n");
    printf("*                                                            *\n");
    printf("*    Enter a number to perform one of the following          *\n");
    printf("*                                                            *\n");
    printf("*    1. Enter Data.                                          *\n");
    printf("*                                                            *\n");
    printf("*    2. Display the data and the following statistics:       *\n");
    printf("*       the number of data items, the high and low values    *\n");
    printf("*       in the data[], the mean, the median, mode,           *\n");
    printf("*       variance and the standard deviation.                 *\n");
    printf("*                                                            *\n");
    printf("*    3. Quit Program                                         *\n");
    printf("*                                                            *\n");
    printf("*------------------------------------------------------------*\n\n");
    printf("Your Choice? ");
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    printf("\n\n\n");

    return choice;      
}
```

Comment: Declare `char com;` before `do while` loop. Try `while(com != '3');`

Comment: I knew about the declaration for the char forgot to post it. But it still doesn't work. It just goes to the default "Not a valid option" even if i enter 1, 2 or 3. If i enter any other characters it gives me a weird loop that just keeps redisplaying the menu.

Comment: Ok i figured out why it messed up. It was the menu I used I was returning an int and not a Char for the menu display selection.

Comment: Never mind still giving me the weird loop still

Comment: As you have declared `char com` before and again declaring it in `while` loop again. This will create problem.

Comment: As you are returning `int` value you can use `int` variable in place of char. Can you post code, how you are using `displaymenu(&count1);`

Comment: Could we see the `displaymenu` function? The error might be there.

Comment: added the full code.

Comment: regarding this line: int displaymenu(int *count1){ the code is returning a character and the calling code is checking for character, so displaymenu() should be returning a char.

Comment: The code is not changing count, so why all the convolutions with the count.  You could simply use the incoming count

Comment: naturally, when the user enters other than 1,2, or 3, the switch jumps to the default case, prints a line and goes around the loop again (thereby re-displaying the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `com` at the top before the while loop and fix your numeric comparison at the bottom of the loop. Here is a working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    char com;
    do{
        com = getchar();
        getchar(); // consume the extra newline from pushing enter
        switch(com){
            case '1':
                printf("Case 1 was hit\n");
                break;
            case '2':
                printf("Case 2 was hit\n");
                break;
            case '3':
                printf("Have a nice day!!!\n\n\n\n\n");
                break;
            default: 
                printf("Not a Valid Option \n\n\n");
                break;  
        }
    }while(com !=('3'));
}
```

Comment: I need the char to return from a menu that is displayed. Its uses a scanf("%c",choice) with a declared return to pass it back to the switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int count1 = *count;
int com;

do{
  com = displaymenu(&count1);
  switch(com){
       case 1:
           enterdata(data, &count1);
           break;
      case 2:
           processdata(data, output, &count1);
           displaydata(data, output, &count1);
         break;
      case 3:
           printf("Have a nice day!!!\n\n\n\n\n");
           break;
      default: 
           printf("Not a Valid Option \n\n\n");
           break;  
     }
}while(com != 3);
```

Make Some change to displaymenu

```
int displaymenu(int *count1){

    int count2 = *count1; 
    int choice;          //make it of int type
/*********


**********/
    printf("Your Choice? ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);   // Get integer value here
    printf("\n\n\n");

    return choice;      
}
```

Comment: I did that originally but if I enter 'A' or 'a' or '+' it causes a crazy loop of the menu redisplaying over and over which i have to kill then with cntrl-c. That is why i want to move it to using the Char instead of Int for the entry that way if 'A' or '+' is entered it just goes to the default.

Comment: Use `clrscr();` in displaymenu

Comment: @PatrickRoanhouse: you need to check the return value from `scanf()` and if it isn't 1, then you need to gobble characters to the next newline (consuming and ignoring alphabetic characters on the way).  This code converts the user-typed `1` (actually `'1'` as a character constant) into `1` because it uses the `%d` conversion specifier instead of `%c`.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` is a bit tricky. There are two things going on here. The first is that `stdin` from console is line-buffered; that is the input won't be processed until enter has been pressed. The second is that `scanf("%c", &c)` reads any character, including white space, so if you enter 3, the stream of chars is `'3'`, `'\n'`.

A quick fix to your problem is to scan all white space before reading the char:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

That will skip any new-line characters that are still left in the stream from previous inputs.

In my opinion, it is not a nice solution, though. It might be better to read a whole line and the take the first from that:

```
char line[20];
char choice = 0;

fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
sscanf(line, " %c", &choice);
```

That's still not okay: What if the user terminates input with Ctrl-D/Ctrl-Z? What if the user doesn't specify a non-space char on the line? You should check the return values of these functions and decide which actions to take in these cases. Ctrl-D should probably terminate the program. A blank line should probably re-read the line. So:

```
int displaymenu()
{
    char choice = 0;
    char line[20];

    // Display the menu

    do {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) {
            choice = '3';
            break;
        }
    } while (sscanf(line, " %c", &choice) < 1);

    printf("\n\n\n");

    return choice;      
}
```

Comment: How would I do an EOF Ctrl-d entry to signal a loop to end. I need to input up to 200 entries of float data into an array that as they get entered keeps a count of the last one entered which terminates entry with a Ctrl-D EOF . It then returns back to the menu screen with the count as the entry of the last entry before the Ctrl-d. If you go back to the data entry screen it asks if you want to add more to the data set if the count >= 1. If you choose no it starts data set entry fresh by setting the count = 0.

Comment: Also the If statement you have in the second code box. Can that if statement call a switch statement?

Comment: That `if` actually handles EOF: `fgets` returns the char buffer itself on success and `NULL` on end of file (or on error). `fscanf` returns ´EOF` on end of file. `sscanf` has no concept of end of file, but returns the number of converted items. EOF is maybe better suited to the end of real files, not of `stdin`, although that works. But I don't think that you can use EOF of `stdin` more than once: If you detect it during input, your menu will probably accept no more input.

Comment: Hmmm, I've made a test here on Cygwin and the multiple EOFs per Ctrl-D/Z work: I've made three subsequent loops, each ecoing ultil EOF; I always was in the correct context and I had to "switch" to the next via Ctrl-D. I havenT# found anything that describes thts as standard behaviour. I suspect that this relies heavily on the shell used.

Comment: Also, in my opinion, raw `stdin` is not very suited for anything other than quick and dirty input. For something like your database, you might want to look into something more powerful, e.g. ncurses.